# Is reputation per-site or common to all sites?

Tags: support, reputation

I noticed I have different values on SO, SU and this one. Is that a temporary thing, or is this intended?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's intentional. For instance, just because I've got a high rep by answering C# questions doesn't mean you can trust me about Exchange Server.

Comment: Additionally, the account-association bonus says "Ok, you have understood the basics of the system on SO, so you get a head start on SF---no need to prove yourself again before we allow you to comment."

Comment: No sir!
People get more reputation point by asking questions than by answering.
Also the trivial funny topics will earn most points.
C# knowledge? 
It’s not based on reputation.

Comment: If I get lots of reputation for answering C[tag] questions I an trusted to answer C#[tag] questions. But if I have lots of reputation on Unix/Linux[site] I am not trusted to answer questions on Ubuntu[site]. Ubuntu is Linux, C is not even similar to C#.

Answer (score 1):

Reputation is supposed to be on a per site basis. Since rep is responsible for unlocking some of the higher level moderator features such as voting to close topics and editing capabilities, it helps if the user has shown that they are familiar enough with both the system and the subject matter before they are given the abilities.